# Swapping Jpeg RGB Channels (RGB->BGR)

Tags: image, colors, jpeg

I have a Jpeg RGB single-scan clip (with Adobe App14 marker, and R, G, B components all interleaved in the same scan). I am wondering if there is way to edit the Jpeg clip header (or append other headers like EXIF) so that decoders can interpret the R channel as B and vice versa without changing the rest of the bitstream?

I had tried swapping the ordering of "Scan component selectors" in the scan header, and the decoder (Windows Photo Viewer in this case) successfully displayed Red as Blue and Blue as Red afterwards. However, the ITU-T.81 Jpeg specification specifically said that "Csj:Scan component selector: Each Csj shall match one of the Ci values specified in the frame header, and the ordering in the scan header shall follow the ordering in the frame header." So I guess changing the Scan component selector ordering is not a valid option unless there is any updated specification saying that this is no longer the restriction.

Does anyone know other ways to swap the RGB channels by either appending some sort of app data or modifying Jpeg frame or scan headers without touching the scan data at all?

Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Are you sure that it is in RGB format? While it is not impossible, I have not heard of an ADOBE JPEG in RGB format. I have heard of YCbCr and YCbCrK.

Comment: @user3344003 - seems illogical (and it isn't very efficient), but yes, Adobe products write JPEG-compressed images with the RGB colorspace.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read the image data, swap the MCU order and write it back. This isn't difficult and won't cause any loss of quality. If you want the decoded image to be in a different color order, then you need to fix the decoder, not the compressed image.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image in raw format you can modify the exif CFA using exiftool. The array may vary depending on the sensor and format.
For swapping dng files, you can use the following

```
exiftool.exe -subifd:cfapattern2="2 1 1 0" file.dng
```

Where

```
0 = Red,
1 = Green,
2 = Blue,
```

If your desperate you could always consider converting your Jpg to Raw and then back again